# Choose between two options on website, should I use buttons or radiobuttons?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on a voting app and I'm trying hard to make it as accessible as possible. But I can't get my head around what the best way is to do this.

I have a question, an explanation about the question and two options to choose from. The current way I've build it is like this:

```
<h2>Do you like apples?</h2>
<p>Apples are a type of fruit and can be sweet or sour.<p>

<button aria-pressed="false" aria-role="button" aria-label="Yes, I like apples">yes</button>
<button aria-pressed="false" aria-role="button" aria-label="No, I don't like apples>no</button>
```

With a small script I will make sure that the button pressed gets an `aria-press="true"`. But then it struck me that it might be better using radiobuttons for this?

```
<h2 id="q-appleTitle" for="q-apple">Do you like apples?</h2>
<p id="q-appleDesc" >Apples are a type of fruit and can be sweet or sour.<p>

<input type="radio" id="qYes" value="yes" aria-describedby="q-appleTitle q-appleDesc">
<label aria-label="Yes, I like apples" for="qYes">Yes</label>

<input type="radio" id="qNo" value="no" aria-describedby="q-appleTitle q-appleDesc">
<label aria-label="No, I don't like apples" for="qNo">No</label>
```

What is the preferred method of doing something like this?

Comment: With buttons a user expects that a press will proceed to the next step. With radiobuttons a user expects to make a choice and press a seperate button to proceed.

Comment: Sounds logical, but what if making a choice automatically proceeds to the next question?

Comment: Typically a radiobutton choice may trigger effects on the same page/ in the same form, like enablig a 'Next' Button that is initially disabled. Or switching additional entries like when 'I like apples' is selected you provide a list of apple varieties to choose from, when 'I don't like apples' is chosen, you display a list of different fruits to choose from.

Comment: To make this usable and accessible the least you can do is allow the user to go back and change their answer. The most I'd say is let them click a Next/Prev button to see any screen. Radios definitely if you can choose only one of a list of items.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes there will also be next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It struck me that it might be better using radio buttons for this?

This should almost certainly be a radio button, due to the fact that for screen reader users this will announce that there are 2 options and which option they have selected (if any).

If these were just buttons they would not know how many options they have to choose from.

### What is the preferred method of doing something like this?

Now as radio buttons are `<input>`s they **must** be contained within a form.

This means for screen reader users "forms mode" is enabled which makes navigating easier etc. As such they **should not** automatically load the next page (as this is not expected behaviour and expected behaviour is key to accessibility).

Instead once an option is selected you should enable a "next" button, which should also be the "submit" button for the form.

As the inputs should now be within a form things like pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit will be automatic so you don't need to worry about implementing all of that.

### Forms behaviour to consider

Final considerations are that to comply with WCAG users should be able to go back and change their answer, or edit their answer later, or if this is part of a multi-part form that once submitted cannot be changed, they should see a summary of all of their selections before the final submission.

This is to ensure you meet [guidance G98: Providing the ability for the user to review and correct answers before submitting](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G98) and [guidance G164: Providing a stated time within which an online request (or transaction) may be amended or cancelled by the user after making the request](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G164)

### Final thoughts

In your second example with the radio buttons your `aria` attributes aren't quite right.

Anything relating to `label` is read **before** `aria-describedby`.

So at present when selecting a radio button it would read:

"Yes, I like apples, Do you like apples? Apples are a type of fruit and can be sweet or sour."

You do not need the description to be read out with each radio button so that makes things easier and perhaps you should use `aria-labelledby` instead and give your `<label>` an id, as that will read any referenced elements in order (so `aria-labelledby="q-appleTitle yourNewLabelID"` instead of your current `aria-describedby`).

Finally, if you do this, there is no need for your `aria-label` on your `<label>` elements. At the moment this is massive overkill.

However for people with cognitive disorders being able to see "Yes, I like apples" would definitely be beneficial, so I would recommend changing the label text to that if space allows, the slight extra verbosity for a screen reader is worth the trade-off.

I haven't tested the below but I would imagine it announces correctly for a screen reader, with a decent fallback using `for=` for [screen readers that don't support `aria-labelledby`](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/).

```
<input type="radio" id="qYes" value="yes" aria-labelledby="q-appleTitle q-appleLabel">
<label id="q-appleLabel" for="qYes">Yes, I like Apples</label>
```

Comment: The code example isn't correct. When you have radio buttons or checkboxes, you need to use the HTML element <fieldset> to represent the group. The question needs to be in the HTML element <legend>. You don't need to use the aria-labelledby attribute when you use the correct HTML elements